# Why is putting style inside if statement not working?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do a basic toggle clicking with js... I have this

```
 <div id="box"></div>
 <button id="btn"></button>

 #box {
   background: black;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   position: absolute;
   left: 50px;
 }
```

js:

```
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
var box = document.getElementById('box');

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){

   if (box.style.left === '50px') {
     box.style.left = '200px'; 
   }

   if (box.style.left === '200px') {
     box.style.left = '50px'; 
   }

});
```

I looked it up and this seems to be the method everyone uses for toggle clicking with pure js so I have no idea why it's not working for me, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Dekel's answer already explains what was wrong with your code. However, you should work with classes instead. Not only is this way faster than retrieving `window.getComputedStyle`, it's also much easier

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var box = document.getElementById('box');
  box.classList.toggle('left-50');
  box.classList.toggle('left-200');
});
```

```css
.left-50 {
  left: 50px;
}

.left-200 {
  left: 200px;
}

#box {
  background: black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="box" class="left-50"></div>
<button id="btn">bt</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You should use the [`window.getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) instead (This way you will get the actual value of the style that applied to that element, and not just what's on the `style` attribute)..
2. You are missing an `else` there (otherwise you will always get the two `if` and nothing will change)

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
var box = document.getElementById('box');

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
   if (window.getComputedStyle(box).left === '50px') {
     box.style.left = '200px'; 
   } else if (window.getComputedStyle(box).left === '200px') {
     box.style.left = '50px'; 
   }

});
```

```css
#box {
   background: black;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   position: absolute;
   left: 50px;
 }
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
 <button id="btn"></button>
```

Comment: If performance is important, `getComputedStyle` may be slower than accessing the style property since it causes a style recalculation. Depends on how much flexibility you need and whether performance matters for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Better use offset. Beside you are making a kind of toggle operation in here. Meanwhile, I modified your script to make it work:

```
 <div id="box"></div>
 <input type="button" id="btn" value=" Try it "> 
<style>
 #box {
   background: black;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   position: absolute;
   left: 50px;
 }

</style> 

<script>
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
var box = document.getElementById('box');

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){


   if (box.offsetLeft == 50 ) {
        box.style.left = 200  ; 

   }
   else if (box.offsetLeft == 200 ) {
        box.style.left = 50; 

   }


});
</script>
```

Comment: this would have been perfect, but I'm using % instead of px in the actual code so using offset might be tricky :/

Comment: I dont see %. any way, can you please clarify your requirement. I see you are toggling position. did you consider jquery toggle() function ?